# How do I make the program remember the guessed letters?

Tags: c#

I am making a hangman game, but I have no idea how to make the program remember the guessed letters.

Here is the code I have:

```
using System;

namespace hangman
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string InputWord;
            char Letter;
        
            Console.Write("give your word here: ");
            InputWoord = Console.ReadLine();
        
            Console.Clear();
        
            for (int i = 0; i < InputWoord.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("_ ");
            }
        
            for (int J = 0; J < 11; J++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("it is turn:  " + J);
            
                Console.Write("guess the letter: ");
                Letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < InputWoord.Length; i++)    
                {
                    if (InputWoord[i] == Letter)         
                    {
                        Console.Write(Letter + " ");
                    }
                    else                           
                    {
                       Console.Write("_ ");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could stored them in a `List<string>`, docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: Save them into a List or array.

Comment: Maybe have a bool array of the same length as the word-to-guess: `true` means the letter at this particular position was already guessed. Then split marking-as-guessed (for the current Letter) and displaying the word (with _ instead on unguessed letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use some kind of collection, for example List:

```
char letter = 'l';
char expectedLetter = 'k';
boolean letterIsGuessed = letter == expectedLetter;
List<String> guessedLetters = new List();
if(letterIsGuessed){
  guesssedLetters.add(letter);
}
```

There may be some syntax mistakes, cause I know java, not c#.